# Create Laravel Package but Command not Listed On Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package

I've been create simple package here is the structure of my directory and using laravel 5.4

```
├── composer.json
└── src
    ├── ArtisanTestmeServiceProvider.php
    └── Commands
        └── TestmeCommand.php
```

my problem is, my custom command not listed on artisan (**php artisan**)

here is the source code of **TestMeCommand.php**

```
<?php

namespace TestMe\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestmeCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'testme:run';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'lorem ipsum';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $this->info("Version : test test");
    }
}
```

and here is the ServiceProvider **ArtisanTestmeServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace TestMe\Commands;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ArtisanTestmeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $commands = [
        'robyfirnandoyusuf\TestMe\Commands\TestmeCommand',
    ];


    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->commands($this->commands);
    }
}
```

and below is **composer.json** in my package

```
{
    "name": "robyfirnandoyusuf/lara-testme",
    "description": "test",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Roby Firnando Yusuf",
            "email": "idonthave@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4":{
            "TestMe\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra":{
        "laravel":{
            "providers":[
                "TestMe\\Commands\\ArtisanTestmeServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and at **composer.json on laravel project** , I've been added :

```
 "repositories":[
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../Packagistku/TestPackage/"
        }
    ],
```

Am I miss something so that my custom command not listed on artisan command ?

Comment: May be due to single quotation in commands array here: `'robyfirnandoyusuf\TestMe\Commands\TestmeCommand'` just remove that and try

Comment: I changed to double quote and remove quotation but still not listed ...

Comment: I mean don't add any quote ;)

Comment: still didn't work ...

Comment: If you run command **php artisan testme:run** its working or not?

Comment: the output is **Command "testme:run" is not defined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#commands), you should be putting the commands method call in the boot method of your service provider.
I would also rename your commands variable or get rid of it at all to avoid any confusion between the commands array and the commands method:

```php
// Do not forget the use statement at the top
use TestMe\Commands\TestmeCommand;

class ArtisanTestmeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->commands([
                TestmeCommand::class,
            ]);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Note:** if you autoload your package with psr-4 namespace `TestMe`, you shouldn't prepend `robyfirnandoyusuf` to the namespace when using it.

---

**Update**
From the chat we found out that the class namespace was incorrect, as the provider was not located in the Commands folder. Updating it accordingly and doing the same with composer.json solved the issue.

Comment: When you do `composer dump-autoload` from the root of your project (not the root of the package), does it tells you that your package's service provider has been recognized and loaded successfully?

Comment: the output is **Generating optimized autoload files**

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4 by the way ... is it doesn't matter ?

Comment: Oh that's the issue, laravel package auto discovery has been introduced in laravel 5.5

Comment: oooh, okay mate.. let me to upgrade it first

Comment: You can register the service provider manually in the `config/app.php` file  if you have to stick to laravel 5.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198728/discussion-between-0x00b0-and-mdexp).